# Contact Us form based on smart group list

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-8

I am getting started with Webforms on Drupal and am looking to create a Contact Us form.

I would like a single form that would allow the user to select the Send To field based on a Smart Group. The group has a list of committee members based on a range of Membership IDs.

A drop down or single selection list is what I would like the user to select from as one of the elements of the form.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling 'Groups' on the Civi processing tab set to user select and then limit the options of groups on the Webform tab in the configuratation for the group component. Once that's done you can set the email to 'Value of "Group(s)'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly -> I would suggest to:

1. create a View of Contacts -> Filter by Group -> expose the Filter so users can select the list of Contacts they would like to see
2. add a link in the View for each row/result -> a button to a Contact form -> pass in the Email address of the Contact to the Webform as an argument
3. in the Webform -> receive the argument and make that the Email to field.
4. configure your webform to send an email to that Email to field.